# Deconstruct with List<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core, tuples, .net-core-2.1, c#-7.3

Is there a way to allow a list of tuples to deconstruct to a `List<T>`?

I get the following compile error with the following code sample:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< Deconstruct.Test>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(int, int)>'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Deconstruct
{
    class Test
    {
        public int A { get; set; } = 0;

        public int B { get; set; } = 0;

        public void Deconstruct(out int a, out int b)
        {
            a = this.A;
            b = this.B;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();

            var (a, b) = test;

            var testList = new List<Test>();

            var tupleList = new List<(int, int)>();

            tupleList = testList; // ERROR HERE....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't use a Value-Tuple and a class interchangeably.

Comment: What would be the desired outcome of `tupleList = testList`? A new independent list containing copies of the original list's elements, converted to tuples? Or a wrapper list reflecting the contents of the original list, projected as tuples?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The idea came about when trying to pass a `List<T>` into a method which accepted a list of tuples as an argument.

Comment: @rhughes in this case it depends on whether the method is supposed to modify the original `List<T>` or not. I guess that it doesn't, in which case @EliahuAaron's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723357/11178549) is completely sufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to explicitly convert the `testList` (`List<Test>`) to `tupleList` (`List<(int, int)>`)

```
tupleList = testList.Select(t => (t.A, t.B)).ToList();
```

#### Explanation:

Your are using the code as if the `Deconstruct` lets you convert a class implementing `Deconstruct` to a  tuple (`ValueTuple`), but that's not what `Deconstruct` dose.

From documentation [Deconstructing tuples and other types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct):

> Starting with C# 7.0, you can retrieve **multiple elements** from a tuple
>   or retrieve multiple field, property, and computed values from an
>   object in a single deconstruct operation. When you deconstruct a
>   tuple, you assign its elements to **individual variables**. When you
>   deconstruct an object, you assign selected values to **individual
>   variables**.

**Deconstruction returns multiple elements to individual variables**, not a tuple (`ValueTuple`).

Attempting to convert a `List<Test>` to a `List<(int, int)>` like this:

```
var testList = new List<Test>();
var tupleList = new List<(int, int)>();
tupleList = testList;
```

cannot work because you cannot convert a `List<Test>` to a `List<(int, int)>`. It will generate a compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(int, int)>'

Attempting to cast each `Test` element to a `(int, int)` like this:

```
tupleList = testList.Cast<(int, int)>().ToList();
```

cannot work because you cannot cast a `Test` to a `(int, int)`. It will generate a run-time error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Attempting to convert a single `Test` element to a `(int, int)` like this:

```
(int, int) tuple = test;
```

cannot work because you cannot convert a `Test` to a `(int, int)`. It will generates a compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Deconstruct.Test' to '(int, int)'